# Passing reference from Python to c++ function wrapped with swig for return value

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pass-by-reference, swig

*Disclaimer, I am a swig and python noob*

I have my own c++ library and I am wrapping it to use in python with swig.

My c++ class is like this:

```
public MyCppClass()
{
public:
   void MyFunction(char* outCharPtr, string& outStr, int& outInt, long& outLong)
   {
         outCharPtr = new char[2];
         outCharPtr[0] = "o";
         outCharPtr[1] = "k";

         outStr = "This is a result";

         outInt = 1;

         outLong = (long)12345;
    }

}
```

Now I wrap this class using swig and say the module is called MyClass.

What I want to achieve in python is the following code (OR SAY PSEUDO CODE because if it was the code it would be working) and output:

```
import module MyClass
from MyClass import MyCppClass

obj = MyCppClass();

outCharPtr = "";
outStr = "";
outInt = 0;
outLong = 0;

obj.MyFunction(outCharPtr, outStr, outInt, outLong);

print(outCharPtr);
print(outStr);
print(outInt);
print(outLong);
```

The output I want is:

```
>>>Ok
>>>This is a result
>>>1
>>>12345
```

I am using python 3.4

I am really apologetic if this is something basic but I have already spent around 8 hours on the resolution and can't come up with anything.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: One problem is that Python doesn't have out parameters.  You've created immutable `str` and `int` Python objects, so that desired syntax won't work.  The objects can't change.  What SWIG can do for you is convert C/C++ output parameters to a tuple of return values.  For example, `outCharPtr,outStr,outInt,outLong = obj.MyFunction()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  I made some modifications to your non-working example:

#### example.i

```
%module example

%include <std_string.i>
%include <cstring.i>

%cstring_bounded_output(char* outCharPtr, 256)
%apply std::string& OUTPUT {std::string& outStr};
%apply int& OUTPUT {int& outInt};
%apply long& OUTPUT {long& outLong};

%inline %{

class MyCppClass
{
public:
   void MyFunction(char* outCharPtr, std::string& outStr, int& outInt, long& outLong)
   {
         outCharPtr[0] = 'o';
         outCharPtr[1] = 'k';
         outCharPtr[2] = '\0';

         outStr = "This is a result";

         outInt = 1;

         outLong = (long)12345;
    }

};

%}
```

Example use:

```
>>> import example
>>> c=example.MyCppClass()
>>> c.MyFunction()
['ok', 'This is a result', 1, 12345]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I actually got this working this way. But is there any other way to do it? Although its working hundred percent correctly, it looks a bit ugly.

Comment: That's the easy way.  It's utilizing pre-built helpers to configure the output parameters.  Those will apply to any functions with parameters named the same way, or you can be even more generic and say `%apply long& OUTPUT {long&};` to make all `long&` parameters output parameters.